# Explain the solution to a cryptic clue for ORIGAMI

Tags: cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords, explanation

Cryptic crossword clue 21 down from Telegraph puzzle #29,363.

```
Sort of art foundation almost inspiring amateur (7)
```

We have the letters O_I_A_I. We believe the answer is ORIGAMI (we came up with it ourselves, but we checked with an online crossword assistant which didn't identify any other possible words). But we don't understand the wordplay part of the clue. It appears to be of the form "definition part, followed by wordplay part" with the definition part being "sort of art".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition

> Is indeed ‘sort of art’

And the wordplay is

> Foundation almost -> ORIGI <strike>N</strike>
> Inspiring amateur -> Inspiring as insertion indicator, and amateur gives ‘am’
>
> Foundation almost inspiring amateur -> ORIG(AM)I  <strike>N</strike>

I haven’t heard of that container indicator used before, but it does appear in [this list](https://www.highlightpress.com.au/containers.html#) of containers (apparently it can mean ‘breathe in’, thanks @jafe!).

The abbreviation also is very uncommon but does appear in things such as ‘pro-am’.

Comment: I was just now typing the same thing.

Comment: Apparently "inspire" can mean "breathe in"... TIL

Comment: @jafe never heard of it in that context before :P

Comment: @jafe and expire also means to breathe out :)